# Cocoapods and compilation flags

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm trying to create Pods and enable user to configure it using Compilation Flags.

Let's assume that I want to use flag named `DISABLE_DESIGNABLES`. I'm unable to add and use this flag in pod after installation.

I've tried to:

- add it to pod project - after `pod install` the flag was not available
- add it to main project - pods still was ignoring flag
- add it to already installed pods

I was adding flag in both Active Compilation Conditions as well as Other Swift Flags.
I was trying to use notations like this:

- `-DDISABLE_DESIGNABLES`
- `-DDISABLE_DESIGNABLES=1`
- `DISABLE_DESIGNABLES`
- `DISABLE_DESIGNABLES=1`
- `"DISABLE_DESIGNABLES"`
- `"DISABLE_DESIGNABLES=1"`

Right now I'm totally confused and have no idea how should I introduce this flag and use it to configure my own-made pods.

Comment: I don't think CocoaPods have a straightforward way to achieve what you need. Amending pod build settings is possible through custom script in the Podfile (remember, it's just a Ruby code), but that's really inconvenient for users.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Any other ideas how to allow user to configure pod before runtime?
The main purpose is to disable rendering of IBDesignables in InterfaceBuilder, cause it likes to loop and crash.

Comment: You can try using multiple [subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) with different settings. Then a user can choose between your subspecs before adding a record to his/her Podfile.